# PostgreSQL: How to list all available datatypes?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

Question:

In PostgreSQL (**using SQL, not the console**), how can I list all available datataypes ?

Ideally like this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Postgre-SQL/Displaysalldatatypesintheconnecteddatabasewithcomments.htm

It should also list user defined types, if there are any.
Just like the list in pgAdmin3 where you define the datatype for a new column in a table.

Comment: Here is a list of built-in types of Postgresql 9.5:
https://gist.github.com/sparebytes/f94867c15059a61ef69dd1882b36c1f6

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"data types" in PostgreSQL actually includes primitive (built-in) types, types added by extensions, user-defined composite types, domains, and table rowtypes. It isn't clear which of these are of interest to you. All types available in a given database are listed in that database's `pg_catalog.pg_type` so you may need to filter the results. See [the documentation for the `pg_type` system catalog table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-type.html).

Types for available but not installed extensions are *not* listed. There's no way to list types provided by extensions not installed in the current database.

To get a prettier listing of types use `psql`'s `\dT *` command. You can see the underlying SQL this executes by running `psql` with the `-E` flag:

```
$ psql -E regress
regress=> \dT *
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(t.oid, 'pg_type') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
**************************
```

Comment: Do you know if the OIDs for built-in types are consistent across server instances and versions?  E.g., will the `date` type always be `1082`?

Comment: @ps2goat For built-in non-extension types, yes, the oids are consistent but you should not rely on this in anything you distribute, expect to be portable, etc. It's not guaranteed to remain the case.

Answer (score 18):

```
select * from pg_type;
```

[pg_type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html)

Comment: do you want to list all types in your particular db, or all datatypes that are avaiable in Postgres?